# How can I give a textBox in Xaml 4 random colors?

Tags: c#, xaml, random

txtbKleuren.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 125, 35)); **I have 4 buttons with the names red, green, blue and yellow and a textblock. So when the color yellow comes on the textblock I have to press button yellow to get a point. How can i make the textblock randomly giving one of the 4 colors?**

*This is my code:*

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Random rand = new Random();

             txtbKleuren.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 125, 35)); 

        }

        private void btnKleur4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

*I don't know how to give a random color to the textbox so i just tried something! Please help me out. I really want to know it! And sorry for my bad Englisch.*

Comment: Random out of four colors only? (Red, Blue, Green, Yellow)?

Comment: Yes or maybe some text like just givin the textbox the text: Green, Blue, red and Yellow in a random way.

Comment: Alright, wait I'm writing the answer. It should work. Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend that you declare your `Random` variable as a class member variable, so that you can access it later, if you need it. It is a good practice to do it this way. So, put it outside any methods/functions:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Coming on to the question, you can first declare an array of the predefined colors (Red, Blue, Green and Yellow):

```
Color[] colors = new Color[]
{
    Colors.Red,
    Colors.Blue,
    Colors.Green,
    Colors.Yellow
};
```

Instead of using `Colors.Yellow`, etc. you can also define custom shades as you did in your question.

Next, use your `rand` variable to generate a random number (between 0 and 3) to use as an index for the array:

```
int randIndex = rand.Next(0, 4); // 0, 3 + 1 -> the Random.Next() function's upper bound is exclusive.
```

Finally, get your random color:

```
Color randColor = colors[randIndex];
txtbKleuren.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(randColor);
```

Or, you can even show both the name of the color and the corresponding Foreground color:

```
Dictionary<string, Color> colors = new Dictionary<string, Color>()
{
    {
        "Red",
        Colors.Red
    },
    {
        "Blue",
        Colors.Blue
    },
    {
        "Green",
        Colors.Green
    },
    {
        "Yellow",
        Colors.Yellow
    }
};

var randColName = colors.ToArray()[randIndex];
txtbKleuren.Text = randColName.Key;
txtbKleuren.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(randColName.Value);
```